# Can I say “the” with a “d” sound in speaking?

Tags: pronunciation

**The** is the most used word in English. However, it is pronounced with voiced *th*, which requires the tongue to be out. For me it is difficult to stick tongue out to say **the** and in to say other words. So I often keep my tongue in and it sounds like a **d**. But I think there’s no noticeable difference when the word is not stressed.

Is it ok to do that in speaking?

Or is there an easier way to pronounce “th” in “the”?

Comment: [Some accents do](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/112409/41273), but it's nonstandard.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it ok to do that in speaking?

It's quite common for non native speakers to pronounce "the" as de or ze and still be perfectly understood.  Native speakers however, are taught from a young age to pronounce "th".

> Or is there an easier way to pronounce “th” in “the”?

I don't stick my tongue out, rather I gently place the tip of my tongue on the back of my top, front teeth (behind) and almost breathe the word.  So if you choose to pursue the "th" sound, try making contact with your tongue and the base of your top teeth and gently breathing air out.

Additionally see the link ["the" without an accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efkSdC-M_fU)